# Window services in C#

Tags: c#

I have created a window service set up project in C# using Visual Studio 2015, I have tested the service in 15 different computers and it worked absolutely fine as I wanted it to be in 9 of them, but I am also getting an Error 1001 while installing on the rest of the computers saying an exception occurred in the OnAfterInstall event handler of System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller-->Cannot start service ATNService on computer '.'.--> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. My codes are :-

ProjectInstaller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceProcess;


namespace ATNService
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller :             
System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, 
    InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName).Start();
    }
    }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ATNService
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
#if DEBUG
        Schedular myService = new Schedular();
        myService.OnDebug();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

#else
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new Schedular()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked Windows Logs?

Comment: Are you sure you are installing the release build?

Comment: No, I haven't checked the windows log yet, the same set up is working absolutely fine in my laptop as well as in others laptop, but its not getting installed in some of the laptops. Yes, i am pretty much sure its the release build.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing the debug build, which keeps running forever.
If is not it, you need to check what it is doing when run, maybe some machines can't access some place on the network or something like this.

Comment: No, I am installing the release build, its working absolutely fine in some of the computers....My service is perfectly displaying messages after 10 minutes interval. I am just getting the above error in some of the computers.

Comment: Where does your service display message? Does it interact with the desktop? If it does, that would be the problem.

Comment: If the installer works without the program running the problem is the program, not the installer and it is another question. :)

Comment: It's trying to run the service (program) OnAfterInstall event handler.

Comment: I have created a class which helps me in displaying all my messages in a text document. I can find everything is working fine, the service starts running as soon as it is installed without me even restarting my computer. My service is perfectly doing its job, but I don't understand why its giving error in some of the other laptops, if you require other codes, i can post that too....